# For loop not saving to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, iteration, key-value-store

First question here, I hope it makes sense how I write this out.

I am searching a massive lists of emails, and if they are found in google (I am in germany, thus the german in the strings) updating the email validity column in the dataframe to reflect it... but it is not saving. It prints correctly, but checking afterwords, it has not stored the iterated values.

```
#  Script googling emails
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://google.de/search?q="Nicolas Cage"')
pyautogui.press('tab', presses=4)
pyautogui.press('enter')

df['email_validity'] = None

for email, domain_validity, email_validity in zip(df['email'], df['domain_validity'], df['email_validity']):
    if domain_validity == True:
        try:
            driver.get(f'https://google.de/search?q="{email}" after:1990')
            time.sleep(3)     # loading url
            """pyautogui.hotkey('escape', presses=2)"""
            time.sleep(2)
            if 'die alle deine Suchbegriffe enthalten' not in driver.page_source and 'übereinstimmenden Dokumente gefunden'not in driver.page_source and 'Es wurden keine Ergebnisse gefunden' not in driver.page_source:
                email_validity = True
                print(email_validity)
            elif 'not a robot' in driver.page_source:
                print('help me!')
                input("write anything, and press enter:")
            else:
                email_validity = False
                print(email_validity)
        except:
            print(email)
    else:
        email_validity = domain_validity
        
driver.close()
print('completed')

df.head()
```

Comment: `email, domain_validity, email_validity` are not associated with your `DataFrame` in any meaningful way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't updated `df` in the loop. Your variables `email`, `domain_validity`, and `email_validity` contain the values from the tuple returned by [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). Changing them does not modify the dataframe.

## df.at

You need to update the dataframe using [`df.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) at the end.

```py
for index, email in enumerate(df['email']):
    email_validity = None

    # the rest of your code

    df.at[index, 'email_validity'] = email_validity
```

## df.apply()

You could also extract your email validation check to a separate function, and use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the whole column instead of looping. You can remove the `if domain_validity == True:` check and use that as a lambda function on `apply` instead.

That might not be straightforward for you since the `'not a robot'` case needs to be handled and return a value.

```py
def check_email_validity(email):
    try:
        driver.get(f'https://google.de/search?q="{email}" after:1990')
        time.sleep(3)     # loading url
        """pyautogui.hotkey('escape', presses=2)"""
        time.sleep(2)
        if 'die alle deine Suchbegriffe enthalten' not in driver.page_source and 'übereinstimmenden Dokumente gefunden'not in driver.page_source and 'Es wurden keine Ergebnisse gefunden' not in driver.page_source:
            return True
        elif 'not a robot' in driver.page_source:
            print('help me!')
            input("write anything, and press enter:")
            # !!!!!!!!!!! This will need to return something
        else:
            return False
    except:
        print(email)

    return None

df['email_validity'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_email_validity(x['email']) if x['domain_validity'] else False, axis=1)
```